# Materialize Css text fields become frozen

Tags: reactjs, material-design, textfield, materialize

I am using materialize css in react. I have implemented a simple text field like this:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
   <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" value={this.state.name}>
   <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
</div>
```

The value is shown in the text field but I cannot edit the field. It has just got frozen with that value. I also used **Materialize.updateTextFields();** in **componentDidMount()**. But it did not work. Any help ?

Comment: I'm not super-familiar with materialize, but I think you also need an onChange on the input, and change the state of the input in the callback for that.

Something similar to:

`<input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" value={this.state.name} onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ name:  e.currentTarget.value }) }}>`

Comment: Hey, thanx... It works.. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since value in your input is dependent on the state, you need to put an onChange handler as well so that you can change the input value by modifying the state.

```js
class SimpleInput extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 'walawe'
    }
  }
  
  onChangeValue = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      value,
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.onChangeValue(e.target.value)}/>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleInput />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

What if I have many inputs? I would use array to store the input. Note that the order of inputs matter.

```js
class SimpleInput extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      values: ['why', 'are', 'you', 'so', 'serious', 'about', 'it', 'all', 'the', 'way']
    }
  }
  
  onChangeValue = (value, i) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const newValues = prevState.values;
      newValues[i] = value;
      return {
        values: newValues,
      };
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.values);
    const inputs = this.state.values.map((val, i) => <div><input type="text" value={val} onChange={(e) => this.onChangeValue(e.target.value, i)}/></div>)
    return (<div>
      {inputs}
    </div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleInput />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Ok...Thanks.. its working. 

But what if I have 10-20 or more text fields ? It's not good to create 10 states for each textfield.

Also, what if I don't use state, instead use props, like this.props.name ?

Comment: @Piyush For the sake of closure, could you accept this answer first? Then I'll let you know what I'd do if there are 10-20 text fields.

Comment: @Piyush added a new code to handle lots of text fields as promised